# Detect touch event in Android Studio from exported unity project activity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, onclick, onclicklistener, touch-event

I have combined a Unity and Android Studio project, so that the app opens a UnityPlayerActivity when the user press a button in the app made in Android Studio to start a 3D-Game.
Everything works fine, but now i need to detect if the user touches the screen, and the go back to the previous activity (outside of the Unity application).

I have looked at the:

```
@Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
   return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
}
```

` And tried to detect the touch from there, but with no luck. I have also tried:

```
@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        } 
}
```

and

```
@Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

    }
}
```

My last try was:

```
mUnityPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {

             }
         });
```

But nothing seems to work. So how can i detect a touch anywhere on the UnityPlayerActivity that came when i exported to Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

The Unity Activity is in foreground so other activities will not receive any event.

You will need to exit the unity activity, so you should implement the code to close the Unity part, inside the unity application.

Look at `Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape)` to know when the back button was pressed.
Also [this question](https://answers.unity.com/questions/369198/how-to-exit-application-in-android-on-back-button.html) has an answer that could help you interacting with the Android activities instead of closing everything (I copy the relevant code here in case the link is broken)

```
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape))
{
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
    {
        AndroidJavaObject activity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer").GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        activity.Call<bool>("moveTaskToBack", true);
    }
    else
    {
         Application.Quit();
    }
 }
```